# Js doesn't fill the input with .val - when i post the form, the variable is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input with an email address named EmailTo

```
<input class="long" type="text" id="EmailTo" name="EmailTo" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->pageVars['EmailTo']); ?>;" />                        

<div class="checker" id="uniform-contacts"><span><input type="checkbox" id="contacts" class="contacts" value="Dorinel Munteanu <test@test.test>" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div>test test &lt;test@test.ro&gt;
```

What I want to do, is to have a checklist under the input and when I check the box then the email will be added in the input. Everything works ok so far. But when I try to submit, the EmailTo variable is empty. If I complete an email by hand, everything works ok. I think it may be something with the JS code:

```
$(".contacts").click(function () {
    var options = "";

    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' && $(this).attr('class') == 'contacts') {
            options += $(this).val() + "; ";
        }
    });
    $("input[name='EmailTo']").val(options);
    $("input[name='EmailTo']").attr('value', options);
    // disable input 
    if (options == '') $("input[name='EmailTo']").removeAttr('disabled');
    if (options.length > 0) $("input[name='EmailTo']").attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

Comment: HTML would be more useful than PHP for a JavaScript question.

Comment: As above, please edit to show generated output, as it is currently hard to visualize the output. As a side note, you appear to have a fixed id within a foreach loop. Duplicate ids will cause problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable an input the value is not sent up to the server. That would be why there is no value being sent to the server. Either use a hidden input field or do not disable the input.

Comment: great this worked. I did not know that disabling will cancel the data, but i have learned one more thing today. Thanks